# slideToggle: Change the text a second time (open -> close -> open -> close...)

Tags: jquery, text, slidetoggle

```
<div id="sidebar_archive_infoline_bottom"><a id="showallnews" href="#">SHOW ALL NEWS</a></div>     

<script>
$('#newsdiv').hide();
$('#showallnews').click(function () {
$('#newsdiv').slideToggle('fast');
$('#showallnews').text('CLOSE')
}); </script>
```

The text "SHOW ALL NEWS" changes to "CLOSE" after clicking the first time on it. Now I need a method to change it from "CLOSE" to "SHOW ALL NEWS" and so on...

Best regards!

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
    $('#newsdiv').hide();
    $('#showallnews').click(function() {
    $('#newsdiv').slideToggle('fast', function() {
        $('#showallnews').text().toLowerCase().indexOf('close') != -1 ? $('#showallnews').text('SHOW ALL NEWS') : $('#showallnews').text('CLOSE');
    });
});​
</script>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ankur20us/BM8jD/1/)

Comment: My plesaure,I updated the code with **callback** that is the perfect way of toggling the title

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#showallnews').click(function () {
$('#newsdiv').slideToggle('fast');
$('#showallnews').addClass("closed");
$('#showallnews').text('CLOSE')
});

$('.closed').click(function(){
$('#newsdiv').slideToggle('fast');
$('#showallnews').removeClass("closed");
$('#showallnews').text('Show all news')

})
```

Not the best way but this can do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
...
 $("#showallnews").toggle(function (){
            $("#showallnews").text("SHOW ALL NEWS")
            .stop();
        }, function(){

            $("#showallnews").text("CLOSE")
            .stop();
        });
</script>
```